# Page content disappears with ASP.NET MVC + jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I downloaded the jquery files and tried to include them in my Site.Master, and the result is that the page html disappears in both IE and FF.

```
<script src="Content/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="Content/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

Firebug shows the first js file, but not the second one, and everything in the body is listed as ""

View source shows all the html content.

Perplexed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use /> to close out SCRIPT tags.  Use `<script ..></script>`.